# Find convex/convave function through two points with given slopes at points

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I am trying to approximate the integral of a poynomial with a square root. For this I intend to split the function at the inflection points into segments and approximate each segment with a function that is convex/concave between the segment's start and end point. The slopes at the points can be calculated.

The problem boils down to finding a function that can be fit to two points and the slopes at the points and is a concave/convex between the two points.

A quadratic function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ cannot be used, because with three parameters only three of the four conditions can be fulfilled.

A cubic function $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ will not work as it often results in non convex/concave functions (functions with inflection points).

Is there a type of function with four parameters that can be fit through two points with given slopes that is always convex or concave between the two points?

Comment: I think you mean: If we are given a function $g(x)$, then is there a convex or concave polynomial $f(x)$ such that the four conditions $f(0)=g(0), f(1)=g(1), f'(0)=g'(0), f'(1)=g'(1)$ are met? The answer is no: if $g(0)=0, g(1)=0, g'(0)=1, g'(1)=1,$ then the approximation polynomial $f(x)$ cannot be convex or concave on $[0,1]$ if the four conditions are satisfied. Does this answer your question? If not then I'm not sure what was meant by the question...

Comment: Are you sure your cubics won't work? The second derivative doesn't change sign between those points so the slope is monotonic there. The counterexample from @AdamRubinson isn't one for your use case.

Comment: @EthanBolker It would be great if that worked, but as I understand it there are cases that will result in an inflection point between the two points if I use a cubic function.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Thanks, but since I split the original function at the inflection points, this case can never happen, as the original function segments are convex/concave. Also, I am not necessarily looking for a polynomial.

Comment: @Waruyama Were I you I would spend some time finding such a counterexample. If you succeed, that's illuminating. If you fail you may be led to a proof that it can't happen.

Comment: @EthanBolker One example is $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=0.5$, $f(1)=1$, $f'(1)=6$. This will result in $f(x)=4.5x^3-4x^2+0.5x$ with an inflection point at $x=8/27$

Comment: Interesting. I think you can solve your problem with part of an arc of an ellipse. The quadratic curve $ax^2+bxy+cy^2 + dx + ey +f = 0$ has five degrees of freedom